is there any reason why a LTS Ubuntu distro doesn't update the patch version of the packages?
is there any reason why a LTS Ubuntu distro doesn't update the patch version of the packages?
For e.g:
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS has libsdl2-2.30.0
now SDL2 version 2.30 is at 2.30.8
Is there any reason why the LTS version is always available with potential buggy/outdated pacakges?
EDIT
This is specific to the bug/patch fixes of a package and it is not related to a newer minor or major version.
So if a package is out with version 1.0.0 and a newer bug fix version is out, there will be a new version 1.0.1.
Why Ubuntu LTS doesn't update that pacakge to use the patched version?

This question is similar to: Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Security fixes are backported to the supported version in the repository for each Ubuntu release.

@guiverc My question is specific to the patch level of the semantic version, not in a change of the version. so if a library has ver 1.0.0 and there is a bug fixes of 1.0.1 ubuntu packages are not updated.
